# Need help with Select Into

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I'm trying to create my first data mart. I am creating my dimension table with a "Select Into"

The code is as follows:

```
select distinct fpc_number, fpc_desc 
into m2mdata01dw..ProdClass
from m2mdata01..INPROD
```

How can I set up a autonumber primary key in this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select *, identity (int)  as myid  
into #temp
from mytable
```

This is the better solution than alter table I think, create the identity at the time you do the selct into.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know you could do that. + 1

Comment: If there was a refuse to be accepted answer feature, I would be using it right now. I hope the OP revisits this, your approach is definitely more elegant.

Comment: +1, I tried numerous ways to specify an identity, but couldn't get the syntax to work, best I could find was the new_id().  This makes my answer wrong.

Comment: I came across this little gem accidentally while looking for something else in BOL about 7 or 8 years ago. It's come in mighty handy ever since.

Comment: duh! I have an example of this exact thing in another answer I posted TODAY (right near the top): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341374/sql-comma-delimted-column-to-rows-then-sum-totals/2341510#2341510

Comment: +1  I too had no idea.  Great solution.  I could have used this thousands of times.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an identity after the select into completes.

```
Alter Table ProdClass add Id int Identity Primary Key
```