# find the number of words starts with vowels in the string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

‘Data base is used to store large amount of data’

I need to find the number of words starts with vowels in the above string. Can any one give me idea to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @str2 varchar(max)='Data base is used to store large amount of data'

Declare @data varchar(max)
Declare @Cnt int
Set @Cnt = 0

While (Charindex(' ',@str2)>0)
Begin
Select @Data = ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@str2,1,Charindex(' ',@str2)-1)))

Set @str2 = Substring(@str2,Charindex(' ',@str2)+1,len(@str2))
if(SUBSTRING(@Data,1,1)='a' or SUBSTRING(@Data,1,1)='e' or SUBSTRING(@Data,1,1)='i' or  SUBSTRING(@Data,1,1)='o' or SUBSTRING(@Data,1,1)='u')
 begin
Set @Cnt = @Cnt + 1
End
End

Select @Data = ltrim(rtrim(@str2))
if(SUBSTRING(@Data,1,1)='a' or SUBSTRING(@Data,1,1)='e' or SUBSTRING(@Data,1,1)='i' or    SUBSTRING(@Data,1,1)='o' or SUBSTRING(@Data,1,1)='u')
 begin
 Set @Cnt = @Cnt + 1
 End

select @Cnt
```

Comment: Is there any other way of doing it without writing function.can we do it through looping string.

Comment: But i dint understand the usage of table declared their.

Comment: sorry I forget to remove count variable. we used the temp table for save the result of splitting process but we can do it without temp table but in this case we will use the count variable. please check the new version of my answer.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use the commonly mentioned "split" user defined function and use it like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.fnSplit(‘Data base is used to store large amount of data’, ' ') x
WHERE x.Value LIKE '[aeiouAEIOU]%'
```

Some examples of the split UDF can be found here: [T-SQL: Opposite to string concatenation - how to split string into multiple records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-recor)

If this is a common query you are running, I think I'd be tempted to consider working out that count at the time the value is inserted into the table and storing the number in the row.

Comment: Is there any other way of doing it without writing function.can we do it through looping string.

Comment: I think we don't need `AEIOU` because `sql` not case sensitive.

Comment: @Miroprocessor - it is if you are using a case sensitive collation.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @S varchar(100) = 'Data base is used to store large amount of data'

;with cte as
(
  select case when upper(left(@S, 1)) in ('A','E','I','O','U') then 1 else 0 end as vow,
         stuff(@S, 1, charindex(' ', @S+' '), '')+' ' as rest
  where len(@S) > 0
  union all
  select case when upper(left(rest, 1)) in ('A','E','I','O','U') then 1 else 0 end as vow,
         stuff(rest, 1, charindex(' ', rest), '') as rest
  from cte         
  where len(rest) > 0
)
select coalesce(sum(vow), 0)
from cte
```

Comment: Could you please explain me the with statement used in the querry.why is that ; and cte is used.

Comment: @Pearl - The `with` is a common table expression. Read more about it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx I this case it is used recursively to get on word for each recursion.

Answer (score 0):

The OP mentioned doing it without a function, so try this for a single string (provided you have a ["Numbers"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393951/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-and-populate-a-numbers-table) table):

```
--sp GEN_FN_GEN_ListToTable
DECLARE @String  varchar(500)
       ,@SplitOn char(1)
SELECT @String='the quick red fox jumped over the lazy brown dog, again.'
      ,@SplitOn=' '


SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS VowelCount
    FROM (SELECT
              LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(List2, number+1, CHARINDEX(@SplitOn, List2, number+1)-number - 1))) AS ListValue
              FROM (
                       SELECT @SplitOn + @String + @SplitOn AS List2
                   ) AS dt
                  INNER JOIN Numbers n ON n.Number < LEN(dt.List2)
              WHERE SUBSTRING(List2, number, 1) = @SplitOn
         ) dt2
    WHERE ListValue IS NOT NULL AND ListValue!='' AND LEFT(ListValue,1) IN ('a','e','i','o','u')
```

OUTPUT:

```
VowelCount
-----------
2

(1 row(s) affected)
```

here is an example of how to count the vowels (function free) with many strings in a table(provided you have a ["Numbers"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393951/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-and-populate-a-numbers-table) table):

```
DECLARE @YourTable table (RowID int, RowValue  varchar(500))

INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (1,'the quick red fox jumped over the lazy brown dog, again.')
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (2,'just another example of some words.')
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (3,'a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z')

SELECT
    RowID,COUNT(*) AS VowelCount
    FROM (SELECT
              RowID, LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(List2, number+1, CHARINDEX(' ', List2, number+1)-number - 1))) AS ListValue
              FROM (SELECT
                       RowID, ' ' + RowValue + ' ' AS List2
                       FROM @YourTable
                   ) AS dt
                  INNER JOIN Numbers n ON n.Number < LEN(dt.List2)
              WHERE SUBSTRING(List2, number, 1) = ' '
         ) dt2
    WHERE ListValue IS NOT NULL AND ListValue!='' AND LEFT(ListValue,1) IN ('a','e','i','o','u')
    GROUP BY RowID
```

OUTPUT:

```
RowID       VowelCount    
----------- -----------
1           2
2           3
3           5

(3 row(s) affected)
```

You basically need to get a split function and then split on a single space, [here is a similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341374/sql-comma-delimted-column-to-rows-then-sum-totals/2341510#2341510) which explains about a split function and the usage of it. I'm not sure why the OP doesn't want to use a function though.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE col_name REGEXP 'vowels'
```

Comment: what is REGEXP ?
Please let me know weather is that a sp ?