# SQL row column sum with spaces between numbers

Tags: mysql, sql

mysql table:

`table_results`:

```
id  results

1   1 0 1 2 4 5
2   5 4 2 6  
3   7 2 8 2 4
```

I'm creating a Yii gridview I need to

```
SELECT SUM(results) AS results2 FROM table_results WHERE id = 1:
```

for example I have to sum first row: 1+0+1+2+4+5 and make as results2 which = 15.

How to do that just in sql?

Comment: Never store data as space/comma separated items in a column, you will get so much trouble... One row/value is the SQL way!

Comment: *How to do that just in sql?* <- with a lot of trouble

Comment: When you generate the results, generate the sum.  And, as a separate column.  That would seem to be the sanest approach.

Comment: You really don't want to store data like this.  However, in the event that you need to do it anyway, look at this question for splitting multiple values out of a field: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471914/can-you-split-explode-a-field-in-a-mysql-query

Comment: here a [similar post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341374/sql-comma-delimted-column-to-rows-then-sum-totals)

Comment: **1+0+1+2+4+5 =13** not 15

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for dynamic SQL. You can use:

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/03fcb/3/0)**

```
SELECT sub.id,  SUM(sub.val) AS `sum`
FROM
(
  SELECT id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.results, ' ', n.n), ' ', -1) AS val
  FROM table_results t 
  CROSS JOIN 
  (
     SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n
       FROM 
      (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
     ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
  ) n
  WHERE n.n <= 1 + (LENGTH(t.results) - LENGTH(REPLACE(t.results, ' ', '')))
) sub
-- WHERE sub.id = 1
GROUP BY sub.id
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is using dynamic SQL.  So, entirely within MySQL:

```
declare @sql varchar(2000);

select @sql = concat('select ', replace(results, ' ', '+'))
from table_results tr
where id = 1;

prepare s from @sql;
execute s;

deallocate prepare s;
```

As a note:  Just because I answered the question does not mean that I condone the data structure.

Comment: I run your code http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e756a/1/3 and for one row it is ok. But for multiple rows I will get multiple resultsets http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c7a372/1

Comment: @lad2025 . . . The question is only about summing the values in one row:  "I have to sum first row".

Comment: I slightly extend your idea to work for all rows: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c7a372/14/4  I will upvote  tomorrow, because I've used all my votes ;)